# how to return the result of (SELECT * FROM TABLE) in a DAO Class

Tags: java

I need to write a DAO Class that should return all 4 columns of an mysql table ( SELECT * FROM TABLE).

this class returns only a list ( one column) I dont know how to change it so it can return an object ( 4 columns --- all rows) 
thank you

**the class below will return a list of only one colum : listID.add(res.getString("ID")); the getString method accepts only one argument, I need the class to return all columnS "ID" "NAME " "GRADE" "GROUPE")

```
public static listID<String> getID() {
        List<String> listID = new LinkedList();
        try {
            Connection cnx = conn.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String requete = "SELECT ID FROM student";
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(requete);
            while (res.next()) {
                listID.add(res.getString("ID"));             }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StudentDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);         }
        return listID;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain your reason for needing to write this DAO? (A school assignment may have very different requirements from real-world uses.)

Comment: Do you have a class for representing the objects you want to return?

Answer (score 1):

To get all rows and column from an "unknown" table, do it like this:

```
public static List<Map<String, Object>> getAll(String tableName) {
    if (! tableName.matches("\\p{Alnum}\\w*")) // to prevent SQL injection
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid table name: " + tableName);
    List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try ( Connection cnx = conn.getConnection();
          Statement stmt = cnx.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName); ) {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Map<String, Object> row = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            for (int column = 1; column <= metaData.getColumnCount(); column++)
                row.put(metaData.getColumnName(column), rs.getObject(column));
            result.add(row);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the sql string to select all the columns, and do the row mapping in the while loop.

You should explicitly select all the columns like "select id, name, address from table", using wildcard * is not a good way in production mode.

Comment: I know but then the class will return a list  of only one colum :          listID.add(res.getString("ID"));    the getString method accepts only one argument, I need the class to return all columnS "ID" "NAME " "GRADE" "GROUPE")..

Comment: while (res.next()) {
  Student  s = new  Student（）          
  s.setID（res.getString("ID”） ）   
 s.setName（(res.getString("NAME”））    like this

Comment: I need to return "ID" "NAME " "GRADE" "GROUPE" --- all for of them .. not only "ID"

Comment: Update comment. All in the while loop.

Comment: Thanks and in main class, Please how to create an iteration to read  all the  results             
               case 5:                  
                newStudent = StudiantsDao.getAllDetails();
                  System.out.println("List of Students + .... ....);
                    break;

Comment: Then you should implement those mapping stuff in studentDao getAllDetails method that return List of students, and create studentService class ,which will call dao method with all the business logic.